# Accessing JSON through Javascript- Different options

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, hosting

Still a newbie. I am building a simple quiz app which I plan to take make public. The questions will be stored in a JSON. Trying to understand the right approach to build this:

The javascript file cannot read the local json file through fetch (URL scheme file not supported) or using jquery (I get CORS error)
I want to expose only part of the json file and different question will be shared everyday.
Do I need a nodejs server to address these requests? What is the right way to host this on a server? When I buy a domain, do I need to keep a server running there to service these requests?
Would appreciate a response on the approach.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are different "Components" in building and deploying an application on the web.

1. To handle the User Interface (Website as we know it), we would require HTML/CSS/Js or a frmaework like React, Vue, Angular etc.
2. This frontend will be connected to a server (backend) that can be developed by using Nodejs(Express), Python(Flask), Java(Spring), Go etc...
3. Then there is a database, you can use SQL or noSQL databases. (As per your requirements, I would recommend using MongoDb Atlas, a hosted cloud database)

Initially, you are going to develop Front-end and backend seperately as deifferent projects. Then Integrate the APIs.
Now, you can either host these projects seperately, or together.

Now, for testing servers, you can use Heroku or Netlify, these services host your projects for free (upto  a certain limit), once you are done with development and testing. You can pay these services or choose other services to host your project and do other stuff like a good domain-name, a SSL certificate etc.

Comment: Appreciate the response. What would be a faster approach: develop the entire app locally (frontend, backend, DB) and then migrate to a hosting service or start building there directly(On MongoDB Atlas). Does local development lead to potential compatibility issues?

Comment: Well, I don't think it really doesn't matter, because you aren't paying anything for it. It's a different stroy if you have to pay for services, And the code is same, whter you use it locally or deployed for DB.